# How do I retrieve multiple values in a CONTAINS condition?

Tags: 8

I'm using the [JSON:API](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi) module (in core since Drupal 8.7), which  works well for a *Retrieve all articles with title that contains "MyKeyValue" or subtitle that contains "MyKeyValue"* which, translated in JSON:API query becomes:

```
fields[node--article]=title,field_subtitle
filter[or-group][group][conjunction]=OR
filter[status][value]=1
filter[title-filter][condition][path]=title
filter[title-filter][condition][operator]=CONTAINS
filter[title-filter][condition][value]=MyKeyValue
filter[title-filter][condition][memberOf]=or-group
filter[subtitle-filter][condition][path]=field_subtitle
filter[subtitle-filter][condition][operator]=CONTAINS
filter[subtitle-filter][condition][value]=MyKeyValue
filter[subtitle-filter][condition][memberOf]=or-group
```

How do I manage multi-values within the `CONTAINS` condition, for a query like the following one?

> Retrieve all articles with title that contains ("MyKeyValue" AND "AnotherKeyValue") or subtitle that contains ("MyKeyValue" AND "AnotherKeyValue")

I tried to pass multiple values in this way, but it doesn't work.

```
filter[title-filter][condition][operator]=CONTAINS
filter[title-filter][condition][value][]=MyKeyValue
filter[title-filter][condition][value][]=AnotherKeyValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change field name and values if you want change the custom name also here its profile status filter.

```
filter[profileStatusFilter][condition] 
[path]=first_field&filter[profileStatusFilter2][condition] 
[path]=second_field&filter[profileStatusFilter][condition] 
[operator]=CONTAINS&filter[profileStatusFilter2][condition] 
[operator]=CONTAINS&filter[profileStatusFilter][condition] 
[value]=first_value&filter[profileStatusFilter2][condition] 
[value]=second_value&filter[profileStatusFilter][condition][memberOf]=billing- 
group&filter[profileStatusFilter2][condition][memberOf]=billing-group
```

Comment: Sorry but if you move rows in your code above with the same order like i wrote in my question you obtain EXACTLY what I've already wrote. So this doesn't answer my question

Comment: ohhh i just copied my working code , i tested in postman too. Check with jsonapi versioning then.